# How to replace a hard disk in SMART array 410i controller, RAID 1 + 0

Tags: hp-proliant, hp-smart-array, raid10

I have a HP ProLiant DL360 G7 server (ILO3). Recently I have been receiving a SMART error message related to drivers.

When checked The Array configuration it was found that,

There are total 8 disks.
All the disks are under one logical drive with `RAID 1 + 0`.
The status of disk on bay 6 is `Missing`.

[image]

Please help me with below queries:

- How can I replace the disk in bay 6 with another disk?
- Would it be ok to replace the disk with another disk which already has data on it?
- How can I check if the data is getting synced?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you do the following:

- you pull out the disk with an orange led on it's tray from enclosure (if there's only one disk with orange led on)
- you disassemble the disk and the tray, change the failed disk and the healthy one
- you push the disk in the same slot in the enclosure
- the *logical drive* rebuild should start immediately

in the same time before inserting new drive in the array you should be sure that its *capacity in sectors* is at least the same as the capacity of the failed drive; being just one sector smaller means it won't be able to serve as an array member.

it's also worth wiping all the data, partitions and label from the disk, but I'm not sure if that's a blocking factor.

You can check the status of the *logical drive* with the hpssacli utility (hpacucli is it's older name):

`hpssacli ctrl slot=<your slot number; usually 0, 1 in some cases> ld all show`

Comment: I see that O.P. doesn't hesitate to stop the server and enter BIOS utility, in that utility you can check the state and sometimes, to force it to become a spare (then it should start a rebuild)